# Comparing a string to a line of text inside a textarea in php

Tags: php, linux

From the topic itself, I need to compare a string to a line of text inside a textarea.

Here's the output i got from php from my linux server which i have program that prints for devices that are available and i put it inside a textarea.

```
Device --------------      |        NAme       ------------------- |        Status  

/dev/ttyS0-----------| Profilic |-------------------|Available

/dev/ttyUSB0 -------| Test | ---------------------|Busy
```

Now I have an array of devices..

```
$devices = array("/dev/ttyS0", "/dev/ttyUSB0", "/dev/ttyUSB1");
```

Now how can i compare my array of strings if the following devices in the textarea exist?

Say if `/dev/ttyS0` found in the textarea then it returns true because i have /dev/ttyS0 in my array of strings.

Sample code how i get output from linux to php.

```
echo "<textarea>";   
echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); 
echo "</textarea>";
```

What i Want to happen.(mockup code)

```
if(/dev/ttyS0 == in the textarea){
  enable this part of code
}

if(/dev/ttyUSB0 == in the textarea){
  enable this part of code
}

and so on....
```

How can i do that?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your device descriptors should appear at the start of a line in the textarea by your format above, you can iterate over the lines and look for `strpos($line, $device) === 0`.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $teextarea_content);
// loop over array of device descriptors
// and make an array of those found in the textarea
$found_devices = array();
foreach ($devices as $device) {
  // Iterate over lines in the textarea
  foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $device) === 0) {
      // And add the device to your array if found, then break
      // out of the inner loop
      $found_devices[] = $device;
      break;
    }
  } 
}
// These are the devices you found...
var_dump($found_devices);

// Finally, enable your blocks.
if (in_array("/dev/ttyUSB0", $found_devices)) {
   // enable for /dev/ttyUSB0
}
// do the same for your other devices as necessary

// OR... You could use a fancy switch in a loop to act on each of the found devices
// Useful if two or more of them require the same action.
foreach ($found_devices as $fd) {
  switch($fd) {
    case '/dev/ttyUSB0':
      // stuff for this device
      break;
    case '/dev/ttyS0':
      // stuff for this device
      break;
    // These two need the same action so use a fallthrough
    case '/dev/ttyS1':
    case '/dev/ttyS2':
      // Stuff for these two...
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do i know what string it compares? e.g /dev/ttyS0 or /dev/ttUSB0? is there a way for me to know that i'm comparing the right string e.g for example i only want to find /dev/ttyS0 in the line of text?

Comment: @demic0de The above will look in the textarea for all the devices in your original array and store everything it finds in `$found_devices`.  If you only want to actually do something with one of them, then do something like `in_array('/dev/oneyouwanted', $found_devices)`.  Or skip the whole thing and just do `preg_match('~^/dev/ttyS0~', $line)` iterating over the exploded lines.

Comment: Hi i got another question it's working alright. thanks to you.. what if the device is found but the status is busy then i don't need to include it in search.. e.g if device /dev/ttyS0 found check for its status if it's busy don't add it in the search. something like that.

Comment: Add another strpos() test in that same `if` statement to skip busy status... `if (strpos($line, $device) === 0 && strpos($line, "Busy") === FALSE) {...}`

Comment: Thanks thanks a million.. i know I'm already spoon feeding but thanks I'm learning. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely want to use AJAX to do this... JQuery makes AJAX very simple.

but your PHP will want to look something along the lines of...

```
<?php
// Already assuming you have filled out your array with devices...
$dev = $_POST["device"];


// This will loop through all of your devices and check if one matched the input.
foreach($devices as $device) {
    if ($device == $dev) {
        // Whatever you want to do if the device matches.
    }
}
?>
```

Cheers

Comment: What has AJAX or JavaScript got to do with this?

Comment: The information has to be submitted in some capacity. AJAX requests just make things look more fluid.

Comment: Thanks a lot but how do i know what string it is comparing?. e.g from your code. if($device == $dev) what device has it found? is it the /dev/ttyS0 or /dev/ttyUSB0?

Comment: That information will be held in `$device`... It depends what you want to do with it.